# Merge and Color style not applying in Apache POI excel 2003 format

Tags: java, excel, excel-2007, apache-poi, excel-2010

In Apache POI, I have apply some styles for some cells and merged those cells. When I open in 2010 or 2007 its works fine, but in 2003 the formatting style is gone. It thorws the compatibility check dialog before saving the 2003 excel file each time.

Please refer the screen shot.

[image]

Below is the sample code :

```
.........
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_50_PERCENT.getIndex());
style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
.........
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

merging the cells

```
CellRangeAddress cr = new CellRangeAddress(10, 10, 18,23);
sheet.addMergedRegion(cr);
```

I removed the merge code, I am getting color in 2003. The style gets applied. But I want both color and merge to be applied in those cells for 2003 version.

Any suggestions!

Comment: It is the same thing in Excel. The cell style of the 1st cell is set as default for the 2nd one. You can merge the cells first and then set the color styles?

Comment: I had interchanged merge and apply color code and not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
int rownum = sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
sheet.addMergedRegion(new Region(10,10,18,23));
HSSFRow row=sheet.createRow(rownum);
HSSFCell secCell=row.createCell(0);


 HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workBook.createCellStyle();
 style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREY_50_PERCENT.getIndex());
 style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
 cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

it may help for beginers. creation of styles must not be done in loops.

Comment: You have not assigned anything to "cell".
How to add style to a region?